# Moving from SVN to GIT

Tags: git, svn

I have a centralized SVN repository which we are currently using right now. But we want to move to GIT. So for that we are thinking of having GIT used for all development, but the main repository will be SVN. So what I want to achieve is that, whenever I push any final changes into the master branch, it should go as a commit to SVN as well, so it should be synced, so that jenkins can take the same existing SVN path for building. What is the best way to do this? Would appreciate if I got some steps for it as well. Thanks

Comment: This should help: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-synchronize/

Answer (score 0):

assuming u use git-svn repositories

this is hacky, but should work without any additional third party tools

write a batch file that commits to git and svn (has to be a git-svn repo)

```
git add . <- adds new stuff
git commit <- commits to git
git svn dcommit <- commits to svn
```

then instead of using the single commands, you can just call the script you wrote

note: if you place it inside the repository itself other people may use it as well, if you dont want that add the script to the ignore-file